# Etymology of 復員

Tags: etymology

As I was reading about a former serviceman, I found out that 復員 actually means DE-mobilisation. My intuition would have been strikingly wrong! It is intuitive that 復 means “re-“ or “again”. But for 員 I would have thought that it meant “serviceman“. Thus, I would have guessed it meant „RE-mobilisation“.

Why is this intuition wrong? Is the meaning of 員 involved the one interpreted in the 漢語大詞典 as 众人 pronounced yun2?

Comment: I think it's that they're "returning" home and not back into the field.

Comment: @Mou某 yes, quite! But why is this implied in 員？

Comment: 復員 --> 恢復在役人員的平民身份 = restore the civilian status of active personnel ; 

Before a serviceman is mobilized, he was a civilian

Answer (score 1):

started from the word “動員”, a translation of mobilisation

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000049169

afterward, people (人員) would return / resume (復 —-> 恢復) their civilian roles prior to the war.

“員” means 4, 5 of this expaltionations:

> 從事某種職業的人。如：「教員」、「服務員」、「公務員」。

> 團體中的一分子。如：「黨員」、「會員」、「團員」。

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000011819

have fun :)